# Get data of dynamically added elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic-content

Very similar problem to [Dynamically added HTML elements can't be found using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416200) but, I want to access new element's data and not its event.

The element is added by JQuery through AJAX request. It is not missing to the DOM when I try to access it.

```
<button id="get-data">Get data</button>
<div id="container">
    <!-- everything here is added through the first ajax call -->
    <button id="update-data">Update</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="elem" data-data="someData" />
</div>
```

So I tried :

```js
$('#elem').data('data');
$(this).parents().find('#elem').data('data');
$(document).find('#elem').data('data');
```

...with no success.

And it's not going to work : JQuery doesn't find `#elem` in the DOM :

```
console.log($('input'));
// OR
console.log($(document).find('input'));
```

...output a list of the `input` items in the DOM, but `#elem` is **not** in this list.

I'm guessing that I can't use `$().find()` nor the direct `$()` to get dynamically added content, so how to I get it ?

Here is how my JS is organized :

```
$(function() {
    $('#get-data').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/"
        }).done(function() {
            $('#container').html(ajaxResult)
        });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#update-data', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/new",
            data: $('#elem').data('data')
        });
        //This ajax call doesn't work as expected because data is missing.
        //#update-data is inserted by the first AJAX call, but the click even is catched without any problem here.
    });
});
```

## Edit after further research:

I tried to output the result of different JQuery selectors :

```
$('#container').find('#elem');
```

> JQuery Object (length: 0) => prevObject : [ input#elem ]

---

```
$('#container').find('#elem').first();
```

> JQuery Object (length: 0) => prevObject : JQuery Object (length: 0) => prevObject : [ input#elem ]

---

```
$('#elem');
//or
$(document).find('#elem');
//or
$('#container #elem');
```

> JQueryObject (length: 0) => prevObject : [ HTMLDocument my_website.com ]

---

```
$('#elem').first();
//or
$(document).find('#elem').first();
//or
$('#container #elem').first();
```

> JQuery Object (length: 0) => prevObject : JQuery Object (length: 0) => prevObject : [ HTMLDocument my_website.com ]

Comment: `#elem` Is this the id of your input? i can see that input doesn't have any id. Can you also share when/where are you accessing this element?

Comment: did you try give the input the id="elem"?

Comment: Woops, forgot to add `id="elem"` in the post. My bad. Editing...

Comment: `$('#elem').data('data');` should work : https://jsfiddle.net/751zcokp/

Comment: Well it doesn't. -_-'

Comment: Man, I suck at creating dummy values from my work ! I don't have the '#' in my work - and it still doesn't work. Even `$('input')` doesn't find it.

Comment: So, you won't be able to find the element until it's appended to the DOM. Right now, `$('#container').html(ajaxResult)` does nothing, because `ajaxResult` is not defined.

Comment: As I said in the post, the item **is** in the DOM - I even checked it with F12 before clicking the 'Update' button.

Comment: HereticMonkey I used `ajaxResult` to make the code lighter in the post - I do some edits to the AJAX response before appending it. Note that it doesn't remove the target `input`

Comment: Ok, there's nothing wrong with jquery here - there's something in the code/html that you've not shown us that's stopping it from working.  Here's a working example of adding html dynamically with jquery working correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/faqzc1uh/   perhaps you can provide a snippet/fiddle with working code demonstrating it not working correctly?  [mcve]

Comment: I'm currently trying to reproduce this. But I get no error/warning from the console... It's getting really strange...

Answer (score 0):

I have this working when I use the hidden selector. They both work below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">

        <button id="get-data">Get data</button>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- everything here is added through the first ajax call -->
            <button id="update-data">Update</button>
            <button id="find-element">Find</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="elem" data-data="someData" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#find-element').bind("click", function () {
            // your statements;

            var boo = $('#elem').data('data');
            var foo = $("#elem:hidden").data('data');
            alert(boo + "\n" + foo);
        }); 



    });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. :-/
JQuery simply doesn't find the div.